# What is the free and fastest way to install all required system drivers in Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers

I've just installed a fresh Ubuntu 15.10 install on a VirtualBox... Is there a way with Ubuntu itself, or with any formal software, to install all drivers fast( CPU\GPU\Printer\whatever) ?

Thanks,

Comment: You should not need any system drivers, so the fastest would be not to install anything.

Comment: @Mateo, If it's a virtual box, surly no drivers are needed? I ask because under "Additional drivers" in the Dash, I do see 3 devices; Each with options to install\configure drivers to it (or something like this)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not mandatory but you could check and install third-party and proprietary drivers under **Additional Drivers** in **Software & Updates**

[image: Additional Drivers Ubuntu]

It can be sometimes useful for finding proprietary Nvidia and ATI fglrx X.org and various Wireless LAN kernel modules.

BTW most hardwares are natively supported and does not require separate drivers to work.

Comment: Thanks to all those who replied to the question and for the answer.